# Projection Transformation from ArcGIS Pro to GeoJSON

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, geojson, mongodb

I have a dataset with points in a layer viewable in ArcGIS Pro where all points are correctly placed on the map. When I export the attribute table to Excel, the data looks like this:

| Year | Country | Area | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007 | USA | Indian River Inlet, Rehoboth Beach | -8328312.727 | 4679513.361 |
| 2019 | USA | Wilmington River, Chatham County | -9001793.829 | 3749369.775 |
| 1936 | USA | Hollywood Beach, just above Mattapoisett Harbor, Buzzards Bay | -8120531.91 | 4913140.686 |
| 2012 | USA | Ballston Beach, Truro, Cape Cod | -8016007.923 | 4967280.039 |
| 2014 | USA | Manomet Point, Plymouth, Plymouth County | -7997079.668 | 4896306.289 |

I (incorrectly) believed that dividing each lat/lon value by 100,000 would give me a value within the proper range (+/-180, +/-90). Plotting those results gives me a map that looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, the southern set of points should surround Florida. The northernmost set of points is too far north - it should be closer to Massachusetts/Cape Cod. I have plotted these points using Excel/Bing maps, and also reformatted the data as GeoJSON and pulled it into MongoDB. Both applications show the same data shifted to the American Midwest. (I don't think Little Rock Arkansas would see shark attack data reported near the capitol!)

I am inexperienced with GIS, but I'm at least aware that my data should be transformed to a different coordinate reference system.

How can I transform the data to show correctly?

Ultimately this data will end up in a MongoDB database as an exercise. The dataset is relatively small, but I am looking to learn how this all works.

Comment: What is the coordinate reference system of your input data? You should be able to get that from your layer properties. It looks like a projected coordinate system, of which there are a great many, taking a stab in the dark isn't an option.

Comment: @MichaelStimson The Projected Coordinate Reference System in the layer properties is "WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)", also EPSG:3857. The Geographic Coordinate System just below that table in properties says "WGS 1984", EPSG:4236.

Comment: You just need to [reproject](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) from EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to EPSG:4326. EPSG:3857 is a "projected" coordinate reference system (CRS) that uses the WGS 1984 datum.  EPSG:4326 is a "geographic" CRS that also uses the WGS 1984 datum.